# Inserting a kernel module via modprobe

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I made a small kernel module called `hello.ko`, and inserted it via `insmod` command and removed it via `rmmod` command.

Now I want to insert this module via the `modprobe` command. 
I copied the `hello.ko` file to `/lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic/` directory and the keyed in the command `sudo modprobe hello.ko` in the `linux` terminal and got the following error :

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module hello.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong and how to insert a kernel module via the `modprobe` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do: "depmod -a" and then "sudo modprobe hello".